# Shopify Liquid: Variables within Filters

Tags: shopify, liquid

Right Now this filter works:

```
{{ line_item.price | times: 2 | money }}
```

I want to able to filter by a variable, something like:

```
{{ line_item.price | times: {{ line_item.quantity }} | money }}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried taking off the `{{ }}` on the line_item.quantity? If I recall it is a number so it should work. Try this `{{ line_item.price | times: line_item.quantity | money }}`

Comment: @JurgenFeuchter actually yes, this did the trick, thanks for the tip. If you want you can answer the question so I can choose this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried taking off the `{{ }}` on the line_item.quantity? If I recall it is a number so it should work.

Try this:

`{{ line_item.price | times: line_item.quantity | money }}`